# Error trying to build to android device "Could not find com.android.support"

Tags: android, react-native

When I run 'react-native run-android' I get the following build error:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.android.support:support-compat:23.0.1.
  Searched in the following locations:
      file:/Users/Travis/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.pom
      file:/Users/Travis/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.jar
      file:/Users/Travis/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.pom
      file:/Users/Travis/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.jar
      file:/Users/Travis/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.pom
      file:/Users/Travis/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.jar
      file:/Users/Travis/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.pom
      file:/Users/Travis/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.jar
      https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.pom
      https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.jar
      file:/Users/Travis/Developer/ReactNative/HayMap/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.pom
      file:/Users/Travis/Developer/ReactNative/HayMap/node_modules/react-native/android/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.jar
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.pom
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.jar
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.pom
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.jar
      https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.pom
      https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/support-compat/23.0.1/support-compat-23.0.1.jar
  Required by:
      project :app > project :tipsi-stripe > com.github.tipsi:CreditCardEntry:1.4.8.10
```

This same error repeats but for other libraries:

- com.android.support:support-core-utils:23.0.1
- com.android.support:support-core-ui:23.0.1
- com.android.support:support-media-compat:23.0.1
- com.android.support:support-fragment:23.0.1

My app/build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wwc.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':tipsi-stripe')
    compile project(':react-native-version-number')
    compile project(':react-native-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-image-crop-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')


    // RNFirebase required dependencies
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"

    // RNFirebase optional dependencies
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0"

    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')){
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
       exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
   }
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'


}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
```

my /build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "23.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see that version (23.0.1) of support-compat https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/support-compat?repo=google try changing it to at least 24.2.1

Comment: @CristianGomez I'm not specifically importing any of these libraries, so I'm not sure where to change it.